# Se item existe na lista, se sim acrescenta mais 1

Tags: javascript

```js
 var prodAdd = false;
     $(".id").each(function(index, value) {
          if ($(value).val() == vId) {
       Swal({
            type: 'info',
            html: '<h5>Produto ja adicionado!</h5>',
            background: 'radial-gradient(#f1f1f1,LightGray)',
            showConfirmButton: true,
           })
             $('#pqnt').val(vQnt + 1)
            prodAdd = true;            
          }
        });


          if (!prodAdd) {

            var cont=0;

            var linha = '<tr class="selected" id="linha'+cont+'">'+
            '<td>'+
            '<input class="id" type="hidden" name="idproduto[]" value="'+vId+'">'+vProduto+
            '</td>'+
            '<td>'+
            '<input id="preco" type="text" class="form-control text-right" name="preco[]" value="'+vPreco+'" onblur="multiplicar();" onblur="formatar();">'+
            '</td>'+    
            '<td>'+
            '<input id="pqnt" type="text" class="form-control text-center" name="qnt[]" value="'+vQnt+'"><span class="vlr">'+   
            '</td>'+ 
            '<td>'+
            '<input  style="text-align: right;" id="subtotal" class="form-control subtotal" type="hidden" value="'+vTotal+'"  readonly  onblur="calcular();">'+
            '<input  style="text-align: right;" type="text" class="form-control subtotalT" id="subtotalT" name="subtotal[]" value="'+numberToReal(vTotal)+'" readonly>'+
            '</td>'+ 
            '<td class="text-center">'+
            '<a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="deleteRow(this)" class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></a>'+
            '</td>'+
            ' </tr>'
            cont++;
            $('#mytbody').append(linha);
            contItem();
            calcular();          


            $(".subtotal").each(function() {
                $(this).blur(function(){                 
                    calcular();
                });
            });


          }
   
  }
```

```html
 <table id="tab" class="table table-striped" style="width: 100%;table-layout:fixed">
                      <thead>
                        <tr>
                          <th id="tab_cab" style="width:15%">Produto</th>
                          <th id="tab_cab" style="width: 8%">Preço</th>
                          <th id="tab_cab" style="width: 7%">Qnt</th>  
                          <th id="tab_cab" style="width: 9%">SubTotal</th>
                          <th id="tab_cab" style="width: 3%;border-left:solid 1px">...</th>
                        </tr>
                      </thead>
                      <tbody id="mytbody">
                      
                      </tbody>            
                    </table>
```

Boa tarde pessoal.

Estou fazendo uma tela de pdv e gostaria de que quando eu adionar o mesmo item mais de uma vez, ele apenas incrementasse na quantidade e vice versa, quando eu remover, ele removesse na quantidade um a um.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: edite a pergunta e insira o código para ficar mais fácil de te ajudar.

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno  OtavioCapel . Veja meu codigo acima. Porem ele incrementa uma vez so e para.

Answer (score 0):

Imagino que você faça o controle dos produtos usando algum identificador do produto, algo do tipo "produto-134", use um `.length` para contar a quantidade do mesmo produto, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno Dev_ps. Tem sim idenficador. Veja meu codigo acima. Porem ele incrementa uma vez so e para

Comment: Já tentou voltar o valor de `prodAdd` para `false` no fim do código?

Comment: Ja tentei, mas nao funcionou. Infelismente.